# Ready as second eventType

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, bind, jquery-events

I currently have a program where if I change settings on the left it automatically changes on the right. So you have a preview what you are doing.

The text will automatically show on each `keyup`. So while you are typing you see a preview how it's going to look.

I currently call my Javascript functions like this.

`"#chapter_form_number"` is then the ID of the form input.

```
$("#chapter_form_number").bind("mouseup" , {key: 'chapter_display_number'} ,    chapter_generate_num);
$("#chapter_form_title").bind("keyup" , {key: 'chapter_display_title'} ,    generate_text);

// Number gen Chapter
function chapter_generate_num(dest){
    var dest = dest.data.key;
    var number = $(this);   
    $("#" + dest).html(number.val());
}

// change text
function generate_text(dest){
    var text = $(this); 
    var dest = dest.data.key;
    $("#" + dest).html(text.val());
}
```

[image]

But it only changed when I `keyup` or `mouseup` on a input. **I would like that it would also change once when it loads.** So it loads the input at least once. So I tried to put ready in the `eventType` but that is not working.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

```
$("#chapter_form_number").bind( "mouseup ready" , {key: 'chapter_display_number'} ,     chapter_generate_num);
$("#chapter_form_title").bind("keyup ready" ,   {key: 'chapter_display_title'} ,    generate_text);
```

Comment: I don't think you can bind `ready` on anything other than the `document` object. I don't think it'll ever fire for other elements.

Comment: How can I call my functions once then, onload? Because it works with $(this)

Comment: You mean `$(this).on('ready', ...)` where **this** is *not the document object* fires? It wont fire even **if it is** the document object.

Comment: This is all covered in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): "The `.ready()` method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted." and "There is also `$(document).on("ready", handler)`, *deprecated as of jQuery 1.8*. This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the ready event has already fired and you try to `.on("ready")` the bound handler will not be executed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$("#chapter_form_number")
    .bind("mouseup" , {key: 'chapter_display_number'}, chapter_generate_num)
    .trigger("mouseup");
$("#chapter_form_title")
    .bind("keyup" , {key: 'chapter_display_title'}, generate_text)
    .trigger("keyup");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call those two functions with the appropriate context (`this` object). Try this

```
$(function() {
     chapter_generate_num.apply($("#chapter_form_number")[0], [{data: {key: 'chapter_display_number'}}])
     generate_text.apply($("#chapter_form_title")[0], [{data: {key: 'chapter_display_title'}}])    
})
```

I am assuming that these two functions are global and defined prior to the onload event.